# Silverlight toolkit animation not working properly

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I added the below code for implement toolkit animation in my application. But it works on the emulator perfectly but in the device nothing is happening, I think the animation happens very fastly or nothing is happening. I cant able to rectify the issue yet. Please some one help me to resolve the issue.

```
 TurnstileTransition turnstileTransition = new TurnstileTransition();
 turnstileTransition.Mode = TurnstileTransitionMode.BackwardOut;
 PhoneApplicationPage phoneApplicationPage =
 (PhoneApplicationPage)(((PhoneApplicationFrame)   
 Application.Current.RootVisual)).Content;
 ITransition transition = turnstileTransition.GetTransition(phoneApplicationPage);
 transition.Completed += delegate { transition.Stop(); };
 transition.Begin();
```

Comment: TurnstileTransition is fairly heavy, try commenting out your code especially data bindings and run the animation again, see if it works.

Comment: I tried, but the result is same...And one interesting thing is that, no such hvy code ir running out there.. still the animation not responds :)

Comment: Oh another thing, do you call your animation in the pages loaded event?

Comment: I added the code in OnNavigatedTo Event. Insted of Load..

Comment: Try downloading the sample code from the toolkit, I am pretty sure you can do this kinda of animations in xaml rather than code behind. This might be because the animation happens before the UI is loaded.

Comment: a quick remark: did you make sure to use a TransitionFrame ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to replace

```
RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
```

with

```
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
```

it's inside `#region Phone application initialization` in App.xaml.cs,

Comment: In my particular case this was what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the XAML alternatives there are examples [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wfaught/archive/2010/11/15/transitions.aspx) and [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide)

Sample:

```
 <!-- Navigation Animations -->
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>

<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
<!-- EO Navigation Animations-->
```

Comment: your answer doesnt make any sence.... Both are doing the same thing. The issue is bcs of some other prob. Try to find out the exact ans nd not misslead the users..

Comment: I thought the issue was peculiar and using the XAML instead of code behind might just solve the issue. Did not intend to mislead. Sorry about that.